# Why is there a difference between functions of Link Class Reference and gazebo::physics::Link Class Reference?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo Version: 7.13.1 
Ubuntu 16.04

 Class Links :

 [Link Class Reference](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html)

[gazebo::physics::Link](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html)

For example, to get absolute pose of a model, function in [Link Class Reference](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html) is WorldPose and in [gazebo::physics::Link](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html) is GetWorldPose. Moreover datatype of poses returned by Link Class and gazebo::physics::Link are different. One is ignition::math::Pose3d and other is math::Pose. Why is there such difference ?

How to overcome this ? For example, how to convert math::Pose to ignition::math::Pose3d ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20044/why-is-there-a-difference-between-functions-of-link-class-reference-and-gazebo::physics::link-class-reference-?/) by [pk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5254/pk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As detailed on the [Migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/annotate/01c7f8b1d68448bc618b575ad1c7ec13fee2b87f/Migration.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Migration.md-528) From Gazebo 7 to Gazebo 8, function

`inline virtual const math::Pose Entity::GetWorldPose() const`

was replaced with

`inline virtual const ignition::math::Pose3d &Entity::WorldPose() const`

When looking through the API documentation, be sure to go check if the documentation's version matches your Gazebo version. For Gazebo 7, [this](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Entity.html#a3fb9c33d26b0c46dd6f735f39bbd15de) is the page you should be looking at.

---

As for converting between  `gazebo::math` and `ignition::math`

```
ignition::math::Something ignSmth = gzSmth.Ign();
gazebo::math::Something gzSmth(ignSmth);
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1